# How properly arrange notifying mechanism between GUI and Model in MVVM?

Tags: c#, mvvm

I faced with a following problem in my MVVM project. I have ViewModel object which has event notify the model when he has property updating from GUI.

This was working properly, but after this it took me updating property in model programmaly and refresh GUI accordingly. 
Therefore i  added event property in the model for VIewModel notifying, and got hanged application.. Since i  got next loop: model -> viewmodel -> GUI -> ViewModel -> model .. etc.

I may use following ways for solution:

1) To create two different methods in the model: for updating property from GUI and for updating programmaly.

2) In the model perform verification  (through reflection)-  which object call the method and later to do  notify or not.

My question in the subject.. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way and what I've seen most often in these cases is to only raise events (INotifyPropertyChanged) if the values of properties actually change, i.e. comparing the new value with the current value.

I'd also be interested in knowing what frameworks you use - it sounds like you're doing a lot of things manually, which are usually handled by MVVM frameworks so you don't need to worry about small details such as this?

Comment: Yes, you`re right, i doing this manually for wpf gui. I think my project is in a state when too late to change my code for MVVM framework (i`m hear  about this framework when you`re posted message). But your advice about INotifyPropertyChanged not will working - this is just pattern which i not use and i`m doing this work also manually..

Comment: My advice still stands - only raise events when values actually change.

Comment: This would provide a stopping condition for the loop. And there are many MVVM frameworks, I wasn't recommending any specific one.